# Storing bash associate-array's values in while loop

Tags: bash, associative-array

I'm trying to write a script that will scan for bluetooth devices and keep track of the name, mac and time the device was first and last seen. I'm running into an issue storing the data into the associated arrays between scans.

On the second scan, I would have thought the arrays would be populated but they aren't. So I'm not able to know the first time I saw a device. I'm pretty sure the problem is the data is being stored into a local version of the arrays and not global but I'm not sure how to fix it.

This is my first attempt at anything beyond very basic shell scripts so any suggestions to any part of the script would be appreciated. I have been googling as I run into problems and have no doubt I'm doing something not 100% correct or efficient.

```
    #!/bin/bash

    declare -A bt_name
    declare -A last_seen
    declare -A first_seen

    while [ 1 ] ; do
            echo ""> ../data/bt_host.log
            date=$(date +%s)
            hcitool -i $1 scan| grep -v Scanning | sed "s/\t/$date, /" | sed "s/\t/, /" | while IFS="," read -r time mac name
            do
                    #debug to see if array values are there from last loop
                    echo "PREFILL-mac: $mac first: ${first_seen[$mac]} name: ${bt_name[$mac]} last: ${last_seen[$mac]}"

                    #populate arrays
                    bt_name["$mac"]="$name"
                    last_seen["$mac"]="$time"

                    #test if have seen this device before or not
                    if [[ ! ${first_seen[$mac]} ]]; then
                            first_seen["$mac"]="$time"
                            echo "Setting first"
                    fi

                    #resulting array values
                    echo "POSTFILL-mac: $mac first: ${first_seen[$mac]} name: ${bt_name[$mac]} last: ${last_seen[$mac]}"

            done
            sleep 10
    done
```

Thanks for the help.

UPDATE:
Found the problem (of coarse right after I ask). It's an issue with the process substitution in my while loop.

I changed it to

```
    while IFS="," read -r time mac name
    do
            #echo "$mac, $name, $time"
            echo "PRE-mac: $mac first: ${first_seen[$mac]} name: ${bt_name[$mac]} last: ${last_seen[$mac]}"
            bt_name["$mac"]="$name"
            last_seen["$mac"]="$time"
            if [[ ! ${first_seen[$mac]} ]]; then
                    first_seen["$mac"]="$time"
                    echo "Setting first"
            fi

            echo "POST-mac: $mac first: ${first_seen[$mac]} name: ${bt_name[$mac]} last: ${last_seen[$mac]}"
    done
```

And that fixed the problem.

If there are any other improvements/suggestions people have, they would be much appreciated.

Sorry for being one search early on asking question.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2):

In bash 4.2 you can ask to run the last  command in the current shell: `shopt -s lastpipe`